# Do C++11 or boost come with a hash function for char*?

Tags: c++, hash

I want to use C-style strings in an unordered_map.  Do C++11 or Boost come with anything that will do the job?  Best I could find was boost::collate::hash, but I don't want to deal with locales, and I suspect being locale-correct will make it slow.  So I'm leaning toward just using MurmurHash3.

In case you're curious I want to use C-style strings instead of std::string because most of the keys are string literals, and that way I can avoid a lot of allocation and copying.

Comment: Take a look at `std::tr1::hash`

Comment: Almost. there is one for std::hash<std::string> already specialized for you.

Comment: std::tr1::hash<char*> just returns the pointer.  Not useful when you have two different instances of the same string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't so I ended up using Murmur hash.